# Copy Command Prompt's content to clipboard

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

I'm looking for a solution to copy the command prompt's current content to the clipboard. I know something similar is possible by redirecting the output or using `clip` but I'm looking for something else. I'm looking for a command which copies the entire content of the command prompt window to the clipboard/a file anytime when it's called(not just the output of one command). It's quite easy to do manually by selecting everything and press ctrl-c but I need a command for this.
Basically it should achieve the same as `doskey /history > somefile.txt` but saving the output of the commands too.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple java program , to get the entire content of the command prompt and out it into a String variable or write it to txt file

Comment: "simple java program" - please consider to provide more information and/or hints where to search / how to start, ideally with a simple example